# Site token with codeigniter rest.

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

So I am trying to interact with the https://www.gosquared.com api with documentation at:

https://www.gosquared.com/developer/api/now/v3/aggregateStats/

Now I am using codeigniter with `REST` and `CURL` I have the following code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('admin/curl');
    $this->load->library('admin/rest');

    $this->rest->initialize(array(
        'server' => 'https://api.gosquared.com/now/v3',
    ));

    $this->rest->api_key('0000000000000000');
    $this->rest->site_token('FFF-000000-F');
}

public function index()
{
  $result = $this->rest->get('aggregateStats');
  var_dump($result);
}
```

So, this is interacting with the service like it should, except on top of an api key this service also requires a `site_token` in order to access my information.

With the code I have now `$this->rest->site_token('FFF-000000-F');` I get this specific error when I load the page:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method REST::site_token()
```

If I remove the line of code causing that error, I get this as a result of `var_dump($result);` (because the site token is not getting passed!)

```
object(stdClass)#27 (2) { ["code"]=> int(4000) ["message"]=> string(162) "You must specify a site token. It looks like GSN-1234567-X and can be found in the developer section of your account area https://www.gosquared.com/home/developer" }
```

**So my question is:**

**How do I pass an extra variable `site_token` into the `rest library` in codeigniter without receiving any error?**

According to the documentation a valid url for interacting with the api would look something like the following (for what it's worth)

```
https://api.gosquared.com/now/v3/aggregateStats?api_key=0000000000000000&site_token=FFF-000000-F
```

Answer (score 0):

By placing the api key and the site_key into an array within the actual request, I was able to make it work.

```
// Removed these lines of code: 
$this->rest->api_key('0000000000000000');
$this->rest->site_token('FFF-000000-F');

// Replaced the $result = $this->rest->get('aggregateStats'); with the following:
$data['result'] = $this->rest->get('aggregateStats', array('api_key' => '0000000000000000','site_token' => 'FFF-000000-F'));
```

Just a side note, may consider placing the api key and the site token into a config file for easier updating in the future.